# How to sort by closest numbers in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a json with numbers and I want to sort this numbers using angularjs by closest position to given number. For example: my array include numbers 1,2,3,4,5. I want to order them by 4. I want to display them as 4,3,5,2,1 (because 3 and 5 are closest to 4 and after that 2 and 1.

Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: This is not really an angular specfic question. The sorting is done with Javascript. Displaying can be done with a filter

Comment: Write a filter implementing this logic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Array.sort` method. Here is an algorithm that could suit your needs:

```js
var closestTo = 4;
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a == closestTo) {
        // a is 4, so must be in first position
        return -1;
    } else if (b == closestTo) {
        // b is 4, so must be in first position
        return 1;
    }
    var deltaA = Math.abs(closestTo - a);
    var deltaB = Math.abs(closestTo - b);
    if (deltaA == deltaB) {
        // a and b are at same distance from 4, so use numerical order
        return a - b;
    } else if (deltaA < deltaB) {
        // if a is at a smaller distance, it should be before b
        return -1;
    } else {
        // b is at a smaller distance, it should be before a
        return 1;
    }
});
```

More details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort